# make a div screen size dependent

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app with Ionic framework and I'm still a novice in css. I created a images slider with timer and but the size of it is fixed. However, I would like to change it to be depends on the screen size and resolution.

This is the html content:

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content-slider">
            <div id="slider">
                <div id="mask">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="first" class="firstanimation">
                            <a href=#><img src="../img/coffe_and_sweet_sale.jpg"/></a>
                            <div class="tooltip"><h1>text 1</h1></div>
                        </li>
                        <li id="second" class="secondanimation">
                            <a href="#"><img src="../img/pizza_sale.png"/></a>
                            <div class="tooltip"><h1>text 2</h1></div>
                        </li>
                        <li id="third" class="thirdanimation">
                            <a href="#"><img src="../img/sandwich_sale.jpg"/></a>
                            <div class="tooltip"><h1>text 3</h1></div>
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

In the

> style.css

I did something like that:

```
#slider{
    background: #000;
    border: 5px solid #eaeaea;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    height: 320px;
    width: 680px; 
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}

#mask{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 310px;
}

#slider ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#slider li{
    width: 680px;
    height: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -325px;
    list-style: none;
}

#slider img{
    width: 680px;
    height: 320px;
}
```

So now it shows the images perfectly but it it doesn't of course fit to any screen.

> EDIT 1

I'm adding the style for the slider animation:

```
#slider li.firstanimation{
    animation: cycle 24s linear infinite;
}

#slider li.secondanimation{
    animation: cycletwo 24s linear infinite;
}
#slider li.thirdanimation{
    animation: cyclethree 24s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cycle{
    0% {top: 0px;}
    3.33% {top: 0px;}
    26.64% {top:0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0;}
    29.97% {top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    30.97% {top:-325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    93.34% {top:-325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    96.67% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
    100% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes cycletwo{
    0% {top: -325px; opacity: 0;}
    26.64% {top: -325px; opacity: 0}
    29.97% {top:0px; opacity: 1;}
    33.3% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
    59.94% {top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0;}
    63.27% {top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    64.27% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
    100% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}
}

@keyframes cyclethree{
    0% {top: -325px; opacity: 0;}
    59.94% {top: -325px; opacity: 0;}
    63.27% {top:0px; opacity: 1;}
    66.6% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
    93.24% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
    96.57% {top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    97.57% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}
    100% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}
}

#slider .tooltip{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 450px;
    height; 60px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 85px;
}

#slider .tooltip h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#slider .tooltip {
    transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: *Does not fit any screen*? It should work fine on most computers, however, in mobiles it might be zoomed out (small) or goes outside the viewport with scrollbar (depending on `viewport meta` tag) Anyway, instead of absolute pixels, use percentage units `%` or viewport units (`vh`, `vw`). Please note that for percentage height to work, you **must** first define height to html and body: `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added one media query for the height. [Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) a link for mediaquery if you want to change something.

As for slider i've fixed the issue now between third and first slide there is a blank slide. I was not sure if it is by design or not. Hope you can fix it if needed.

```
   #slider{
    background: #000;
    border: 5px solid #eaeaea;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    height: 320px;
    width: 80%; 
    max-width: 680px;
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
  }

  #mask{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 310px;
  }

  #slider ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 320px;
    width: inherit;
    position: relative;
  }

  #slider a{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }  

  #slider li{
    width: inherit;
    height: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    list-style: none;
  }

  #slider img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
  }
  #slider li.firstanimation{
    animation: cycle 24s linear infinite;
  }

  #slider li.secondanimation{
    animation: cycletwo 24s linear infinite;
  }
  #slider li.thirdanimation{
    animation: cyclethree 24s linear infinite;
  }

  @keyframes cycle{
    0% {top: 0px;}
    3.33% {top: 0px;}
    26.64% {top:0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0;}
    29.97% {top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    30.97% {top:-325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    93.34% {top:-325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    96.67% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
    100% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
  }

  @keyframes cycletwo{
    0% {top: -325px; opacity: 0;}
    26.64% {top: -325px; opacity: 0}
    29.97% {top:0px; opacity: 1;}
    33.3% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
    59.94% {top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0;}
    63.27% {top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    64.27% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
    100% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}
  }

  @keyframes cyclethree{
    0% {top: -325px; opacity: 0;}
    59.94% {top: -325px; opacity: 0;}
    63.27% {top:0px; opacity: 1;}
    66.6% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
    93.24% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
    96.57% {top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0;}
    97.57% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}
    100% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}
  }

  #slider .tooltip{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 60%;
    height; 60px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 85px;
  }

  #slider .tooltip h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  }

  #slider .tooltip {
    transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
  }

  @media screen and (max-height: 380px){
    #slider{
      height: 200px;
    }

    #mask{
      height:190px;
    }

    #slider img{
      height:190px;
    }

    #slider li{
      height:190px;
    }

    #slider ul{
      height:190px;
    }

    #slider .tooltip{
      bottom: 80px;
    }        
  }
```

Comment: Well now the width reacts to the screen size but the height doesn't and also the animation does not work properly, Only the first image is being shown for a few seconds and than there is a black slider for a few more seconds and than the first image returns and so on,,

Comment: Generally heights are kept same but if you want i can configure different heights for different screen ranges. Also can i get your code for slider so that i can test it and provide you with better solution.

Comment: Ok now It is working good. I'll go over the code and change minor things that but everything is great! By the way, canyou please suggest me on how to learn css? I am an  experienced programmer but css was always my weakest link. I want to fix that

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
#slider img{
  max-width:100%;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

Remove absolute values of your image.

Comment: I want the entire slider to change when the screen is changes

Comment: in that case you can use the same rule on `#slider`

Comment: and what about the mask?

Comment: @kitsuneFox what have you used mask for?

Comment: The mask class hides all of the elements that lie outside of the slider. its height must be equal to the height of the slider

Comment: Yes, you will have to do this relative width changes in all the child elements.

Comment: Can you please post an answer with all changes?